# A rod lies on a smooth surface and a ball hits it at one end and gets stuck to it

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

I know how to solve these kind of questions but here since it is an inelastic collision I have some doubts. I checked the solution where they conserved linear momentum as: $(M+m)v=mu$ [$v$ is final, $u$ is initial]. My doubt is that shouldn't it be $Mv+m(v+rw)=mu$, where $w$ is the angular velocity of the system and $r$ is the distance of the ball from the center of mass of the system.

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't be. For linear momentum, we simply use the mass of the system and the velocity of center of mass of system.